# LeetCode 1044: Longest Duplicate Substring

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++17

I'm posting my C++ code for LeetCode's [Longest Duplicate Substring](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-duplicate-substring/). If you have time and would like to review, please do so. Thank you!

### Problem

> - Given a string S, consider all duplicated substrings: (contiguous) substrings of S that occur 2 or more times.  (The occurrences may
>   overlap.)
> - Return any duplicated substring that has the longest possible length.  (If S does not have a duplicated substring, the answer is
>   "".)
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> - Input: "banana"
> - Output: "ana"
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> - Input: "abcd"
> - Output: ""
>
> #### Note:
>
> - 2 <= S.length <= 10^5
> - S consists of lowercase English letters.

#### Accepted C++

```
class Solution {
private:
    const int prime = 19260817;
    const int a_decimal = 65;
    const int char_size = 26;
    std::string res = "";
    std::vector<int> exponent;

    // Wikipedia
    // The Rabin–Karp algorithm or Karp–Rabin algorithm is a string - searching algorithm that uses hashing to find an exact match of a pattern string in a text. 
    // It uses a rolling hash to quickly filter out positions of the text that cannot match the pattern, 
    // and then checks for a match at the remaining positions. 
    const std::string rabin_karp_search(const int length, const string& base) {
        if (length == 0) {
            return "";
        }

        std::unordered_map<int, vector<int>> hash_map = unordered_map<int, vector<int>>(); // hash memorization 
        long long curr = 0; // current hash
        int index; 

        for (index = 0; index < length; index++) {
            curr = ((curr * char_size) % prime + (base[index] - a_decimal)) % prime;
        }

        hash_map[curr] = std::vector<int>(1, 0);

        for (index = length; index < base.length(); index++) {
            curr = ((curr - (long long) exponent[length - 1] * (base[index - length] - a_decimal)) % prime + prime) % prime;
            curr = (curr * char_size + (base[index] - a_decimal)) % prime;

            if (hash_map.find(curr) == hash_map.end()) {
                hash_map[curr] = std::vector<int>(1, -~index - length);

            } else {
                for (const auto iter : hash_map[curr]) {
                    if (std::strcmp((base.substr(iter, length)).data(), base.substr(-~index - length, length).data()) == 0) {
                        return base.substr(iter, length);
                    }
                }

                hash_map[curr].push_back(-~index - length);
            }
        }

        return "";
    }

    // Wikipedia
    // binary search is a search algorithm that finds the position of a target value within a sorted array.
    // Binary search compares the target value to the middle element of the array. 
    // If they are not equal, the half in which the target cannot lie is eliminated and the search continues on the remaining half, 
    // again taking the middle element to compare to the target value, and repeating this until the target value is found. 
    // If the search ends with the remaining half being empty, the target is not in the array.

    const std::string get_longest_binary_search(std::string base_string, std::string res) {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = base_string.length();

        while (lo <= hi) {
            int mid = lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1);
            std::string temp = rabin_karp_search(mid, base_string);

            if (temp.length() == 0) {
                hi = mid - 1;

            } else {
                if (temp.length() > res.length()) {
                    res = temp;
                }

                lo = -~mid;
            }
        }

        return res;
    }

public:
    const std::string longestDupSubstring(const std::string base_string) {
        res = "";
        exponent = std::vector<int>(base_string.length(), 1);
        int index;

        for (index = 1; index < base_string.length(); index++) {
            exponent[index] = (exponent[index - 1] * char_size) % prime;
        }

        return get_longest_binary_search(base_string, res);
    }

};
```

#### LeetCode Solution in Java with additional comments (Not for review)

```
class Solution {
  /*
  Rabin-Karp with polynomial rolling hash.
      Search a substring of given length
      that occurs at least 2 times.
      Return start position if the substring exits and -1 otherwise.
      */
  public int search(int L, int a, long modulus, int n, int[] nums) {
    // compute the hash of string S[:L]
    long h = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < L; ++i) h = (h * a + nums[i]) % modulus;

    // already seen hashes of strings of length L
    HashSet<Long> seen = new HashSet();
    seen.add(h);
    // const value to be used often : a**L % modulus
    long aL = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= L; ++i) aL = (aL * a) % modulus;

    for(int start = 1; start < n - L + 1; ++start) {
      // compute rolling hash in O(1) time
      h = (h * a - nums[start - 1] * aL % modulus + modulus) % modulus;
      h = (h + nums[start + L - 1]) % modulus;
      if (seen.contains(h)) return start;
      seen.add(h);
    }
    return -1;
  }

  public String longestDupSubstring(String S) {
    int n = S.length();
    // convert string to array of integers
    // to implement constant time slice
    int[] nums = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) nums[i] = (int)S.charAt(i) - (int)'a';
    // base value for the rolling hash function
    int a = 26;
    // modulus value for the rolling hash function to avoid overflow
    long modulus = (long)Math.pow(2, 32);

    // binary search, L = repeating string length
    int left = 1, right = n;
    int L;
    while (left <= right) {
      L = left + (right - left) / 2;
      if (search(L, a, modulus, n, nums) != -1) left = L + 1;
      else right = L - 1;
    }

    int start = search(left - 1, a, modulus, n, nums);
    return S.substring(start, start + left - 1);
  }
}
```

#### Reference

LeetCode is a platform only for [interviewing](https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question?currentPage=1&orderBy=hot&query=) and [competitive programming](https://leetcode.com/contest/globalranking). On LeetCode, there is a class usually named `Solution` with one or more `public` functions which we are not allowed to rename.

- [1044. Longest Duplicate Substring - Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-duplicate-substring/)
- [1044. Longest Duplicate Substring - Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-duplicate-substring/discuss/)
- [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)
- [Rabin Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Avoid unnecessary member variables

You added `res` and `exponent` as member variables. However, they are only used inside `longestDupSubString()` and functions called by it. You should just declare them inside `longestDupSubString()` instead, and pass them by reference to other functions if necessary. But see below for why these variables might not be necessary at all.

## Use character constants

Write `const int a_decimal = 'a'`, so there is no need to know the ASCII table and no possibility for errors. However, then the question is, why define `a_decimal` at all? It seems you want to force integer promotion, but you can make that more explicit. Instead of `base[index] - a_decimal`, you can write `(int)base[index] - 'a'`.

But this makes me wonder, why subtract `'a'` at all? Sure, the question says the input consists of only lowercase English numbers, but you can keep your solution generic.

## Don't return `const` values

There is no point in returning something by `const` value. The following is perfectly valid:

```
const std::string foo() {
    return "foo";
}

std::string bar = foo();
```

It only makes sense to make the return type `const` if you are return a pointer or reference.

## Avoid `using namespace std` and/or `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`

I see you forgot to add `std::` to some standard library types, implying that you have `using namespace std` somewhere or are using the non-standard `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.

## Give proper names to variables

Some of your naming choices are questionable:

- `char_size`: sounds like it would hold the result of `sizeof(char)`, but unstead it's the number of letters in the alphabet. Maybe `alphabet_size` would be better.
- `hash_map`: the name is equivalent to  the type (`std::unordered_map`), but what you should have used is something that represents what information the hash map holds: substrings that you already visited. So maybe `visited_substrings` is a better name.
- `index`: this is one of the few times you can use a one-letter variable, like `i`, since that is the idiomatic name for a loop counter in C++.
- `iter`: in `for(const auto iter: hash_map[curr])`, the variable `iter` is not an iterator, but actually holds the value of one of the elements of a `std::vector<int>`. So `element`, `item` or `entry` would already be a better name, but even better is a name that reflects what that elements represents, namely an offset into the base string, so `offset` would be a good name here.

## Your hash function can have collisions, and is unnecessary

Your hash function can have collisions if you ever have substrings longer than 32 / log₂(26) = 6 characters. A collision would not be a problem if you would handle them, but you don't. Also, there is no need to create a hash yourself, since `std::unordered_map` already does that for you! Just pass the substring to it directly:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> visited_substrings;

auto substring = base.substr(0, length);
visited_substrings[substring] = {0};
```

## Avoid repeating type names

There are a few places where you can avoid repeating type names. As shown above, when declaring a variable of type `std::unordered_map`, it is already initialized to be an empty map, so no need to explicity initialize it with another empty map.

When assigning to an element of a `std::unordered_map`, you can use an initializer list, and since the compiler knows the type of the map elements, you don't have to repeat that yourself. So `visited_substrings[substring] = {0}` will initialize the vector with one integer with value `0`.

## Don't use C library functions if there are perfectly fine C++ equivalents

When comparing C++ strings, don't use `strcmp()`, but rather use the tools the `std::string` class provides you. In particular, you can just use the `==` operator:

```
if (base.substr(offset, length) == base.substr(index + 1 - length, length)) {
    return base.substr(offset, length);
}
```

Also, `std::string` comes with the member function `compare()` that can compare substrings directly:

```
if (base.compare(offset, length, base, index + 1 - length, length) == 0) {
    return base.substr(offset, length);
}
```

Although it doesn't look like much of an improvement, it avoids having to create new temporary strings to hold the substrings.

## Don't use bit twiddling tricks unnecessarily

There is no need to write `-~index` when you can just write `index + 1`. The latter is much clearer. Also, `-~index` being equivalent to `index + 1` assumes [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of integers, which is not guaranteed in C++17 (it is only since C++20).

Also, in `int mid = lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1)`, just write `int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2`, it is much clearer what the intention is. If you could use C++20, then you should use [`std::midpoint()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/midpoint) here, since there are [many pitfalls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBtAGxBh-XI) in your simple approach, although it works fine in the constraints of this LeetCode problem.

## Use unsigned integers where appropriate

For array indices, sizes and non-negative offsets, you should unsigned integers, or even better `size_t`. There are several reasons for this:

- There's less chance of overflow. Note that unintended overlow might be a security issue.
- When using unsigned integers as function parameters, you never have to check whether they are non-negative if that is not allowed.
- There are less surprises when doing bitwise operations on unsigned integers.
- Some common standard library functions, such as `std::string::size()`, also return unsigned integers, so you won't get warnings about comparing signed to unsigned numbers.

Regarding that last point, ensure you have compiler warnings enabled and fix all warnings it produces.

Comment: Please add indexes to the list of where unsigned integers are appropriate. It might be good to explain why unsigned is better (integer overflow comes to mind).

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty long video, but it's worth viewing every minute of it.

Answer (score 2):

G. Sliepen wrote a rather comprehensive review, I'm going to expand on one point in their review, and add 2 others.

> **Avoid using namespace std and/or #include <bits/stdc++.h>**

> I see you forgot to add std:: to some standard library types, implying that you have using namespace std somewhere or are using the non-standard #include <bits/stdc++.h>.

The LeetCode is doing this for you and it is promoting bad habits that you need to unlearn. The proper includes for this code are

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
```

If you are coding professionally you probably should get out of the habit of using the `using namespace std;` statement. The code will more clearly define where `cout` and other identifiers are coming from (`std::cin`, `std::cout`). As you start using namespaces in your code it is better to identify where each function comes from because there may be function name collisions from different namespaces. The identifier`cout` you may override within your own classes, and you may override the operator `<<` in your own classes as well. This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) discusses this in more detail.

**More on Private, Protected and Public**
I see that you do learn from your [previous reviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244186/leetcode-1146-snapshot-array) and that is a good thing. In the following code the keyword `private:` is not necessary, when you first open a class declaration and variables, methods and functions are private by default.

```
class Solution {
private:
    const int prime = 19260817;
    const int a_decimal = 65;
    const int char_size = 26;
    std::string res = "";
    std::vector<int> exponent;
```

You will find that a lot of C++ programmers are no long using the first section of a class declaration because it is better to put the public interfaces at the beginning of a class so that users of that class can find the public interfaces easily. This actually applies to most object oriented programming languages. The general hierarchy is public first, then protected and then private.

**Class File Structure**
My concern here is that you're only learning C++ through `LeetCode` that you are learning some bad habits that will need to be replaced at some point. C++ is generally broken up into header files and source files. You are fairly familiar with the header file grammar but you are not familiar with the source file grammar.

Historically the C++ programming language grew out of the C programming language which already had separate header files and source files. Unlike Java and C# most of the member functions and methods have function prototypes in the class declaration and the actual functions are defined in a `.cpp` file. There are a couple of reasons for this, the first is that it allows bugs to be fixed in the code while not affecting the public interfaces. This means that patches or updated dynamically linked libraries can be developed and shipped to fix bugs without redoing the entire application. The other reason is that compile / build times are improved by reducing the contents of the header files.

There are 2 exceptions to this,

1. For performance reasons if a function or method is not very complex it can be included in the header so that the compiler can try to `inline` it. This means that the code of the function will replace the function call where it is used.
2. There are complete libraries such as the [Boost Library](https://www.boost.org/) in `.hpp` files that provide a great deal of additional functionality (maybe even a binary search).

This is what the solutions class might look like in this case:

**Solution.h**

```
#ifndef LEETCODE1044_SOLUTION_H
#define LEETCODE1044_SOLUTION_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class Solution {
private:
    const int prime = 19260817;
    const int a_decimal = 65;
    const int char_size = 26;
    std::string res = "";
    std::vector<int> exponent;

    // Wikipedia
    // The Rabin–Karp algorithm or Karp–Rabin algorithm is a string - searching algorithm that uses hashing to find an exact match of a pattern string in a text.
    // It uses a rolling hash to quickly filter out positions of the text that cannot match the pattern,
    // and then checks for a match at the remaining positions.
    const std::string rabin_karp_search(const int length, const std::string& base);

    // Wikipedia
    // binary search is a search algorithm that finds the position of a target value within a sorted array.
    // Binary search compares the target value to the middle element of the array.
    // If they are not equal, the half in which the target cannot lie is eliminated and the search continues on the remaining half,
    // again taking the middle element to compare to the target value, and repeating this until the target value is found.
    // If the search ends with the remaining half being empty, the target is not in the array.

    const std::string get_longest_binary_search(std::string base_string, std::string res);

public:
    const std::string longestDupSubstring(const std::string base_string);

};

#endif //LEETCODE1044_SOLUTION_H
```

**Solution.cpp**

```
#include "Solution.h"

const std::string Solution::rabin_karp_search(const int length, const std::string &base)
{
    if (length == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> hash_map = std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>>(); // hash memorization
    long long curr = 0; // current hash
    int index;

    for (index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        curr = ((curr * char_size) % prime + (base[index] - a_decimal)) % prime;
    }

    hash_map[curr] = std::vector<int>(1, 0);

    for (index = length; index < base.length(); index++) {
        curr = ((curr - (long long) exponent[length - 1] * (base[index - length] - a_decimal)) % prime + prime) % prime;
        curr = (curr * char_size + (base[index] - a_decimal)) % prime;

        if (hash_map.find(curr) == hash_map.end()) {
            hash_map[curr] = std::vector<int>(1, -~index - length);

        } else {
            for (const auto iter : hash_map[curr]) {
                if (std::strcmp((base.substr(iter, length)).data(), base.substr(-~index - length, length).data()) == 0) {
                    return base.substr(iter, length);
                }
            }

            hash_map[curr].push_back(-~index - length);
        }
    }

    return "";
}

const std::string Solution::get_longest_binary_search(std::string base_string, std::string res)
{
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = base_string.length();

    while (lo <= hi) {
        int mid = lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1);
        std::string temp = rabin_karp_search(mid, base_string);

        if (temp.length() == 0) {
            hi = mid - 1;

        } else {
            if (temp.length() > res.length()) {
                res = temp;
            }

            lo = -~mid;
        }
    }

    return res;
}

const std::string Solution::longestDupSubstring(const std::string base_string)
{
    res = "";
    exponent = std::vector<int>(base_string.length(), 1);
    int index;

    for (index = 1; index < base_string.length(); index++) {
        exponent[index] = (exponent[index - 1] * char_size) % prime;
    }

    return get_longest_binary_search(base_string, res);
}
```

Comment: Good points about bad habits taught by LeetCode. Another one is that a `class` is used at all. That might be necessary in Java, but in C++ `longestDupSubString()` could just be a stand-alone function.

Comment: @G.Sliepen You're correct, it is forcing the usage of C++ as an object oriented language when it doesn't need to, but it also encapsulates all the code (any supporting functions).